# SEO with hidden content

Tags: seo

On [this page](http://industry.bnet.com/retail/10004450/gap-stands-behind-flailing-banana-republic/?tag=content;col1) can Google (or any other search engine) see the content that is hidden in the right splash where it says "More Posts" (click it to see everything) or can they only see the first 5 links?

Comment: Please post a screenshot and remove the link.  The link will not work forever.

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can, but they don't.

This is to avoid spammers to create pages with dummy but hidden content just to appear in top results.

In other words, hidden content does not help you with your SEO strategy - you need everything to be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The 'more posts' are already added to the page as an unordered list, so the content is there to crawl. Google's pretty smart.

Comment: Surely you mean, "Google's pretty dumb" because it sees them in the code, but they're not visible on the page.

Comment: I think in the example provided, the *intention* was to have all that content there and be available, just use the space provided in the initial view. I would tend to agree with you more if it were something like pagination and the "more" was generating a page request. I get what you mean though so +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes - Any search engine bot is going to pick it up because it is rendered to the page (IE not AJAX'd content.)

Your method is using CSS to show/hide the content which means that it is going to be visible to a spider.  If you want to get a good idea of what search engines see, load up the page without any stylesheets or javascript.

---

As an aside, the "Banana Fall Line" image is loading really poorly because you're using a large image and scaling it down with width/height in the image tag.

Comment: yea this page has a lot of probs, it's not my page i'm just hunting around for ideas for a redesign of my own.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes they will be able to see those links like Typeoneerror said, if you view the source of that page, you will see the links appearing in another div which is simply hidden at the start. You can use oyoy.eu use the spider simulation function.

Answer (score 0):

Most bots send out a special HTTP Header called `User-Agent`. Google's is `User-Agent: Googlebot/2.1` for example.

Also Google has a `published range of IP addresses` from which their spiders crawl. A smart `web server module` can *customize* your content based upon if it detects *googlebot* or not.

---

Some consider this to be **blackhat SEO**. Showing the search crawler something *different* than what the user sees.

See [Googlebot Spoofer](http://www.smart-it-consulting.com/internet/google/googlebot-spoofer/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

look at the Google cache and then look at the text only version (click the "text only" link on the upper right.) That shows what google has indexed.

It looks to me like only the first 5.